# Java Methods returning Interface types

Tags: java, class, types, interface, implementation

I've seen related questions, but the answers only skirt the heart of the answer I'm looking for.

I have the following line of code (and it compiles and runs without error):

`Document doc = dbuilder.parse(myXmlFile);`

where
Document is the interface `org.w3c.dom.Document`
and
`parse()` is a method from `javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder`

When I then executed

```
System.out.println(doc.getClass().getName());
```

its output is

```
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl
```

which, I assume, means that `DeferredDocumentImpl` implements the `Document` interface, and that when I execute methods against my doc variable, I'm actually executing the methods of DeferredDocumentImpl.

My questions are:

1. Is that above assumption correct, that is, am I indeed executing the implemented methods of that `DeferredDocumentImpl` class?
2. An interface can be implemented by any number of classes, and assuming that `org.w3c.dom.Document` is indeed implemented by multiple classes, why did the `Document` type returned by `parse()` get cast as the `DeferredDocumentImpl` class, and not one of the other classes that implements `Document`?
3. Assuming that 2. above is some kind of 'default' or 'priority' type-assignment, where do I verify - and possibly change - that assignment?
4. How would I override the type-assignment I describe in 3. above at the level of the code itself?

As I say, I've searched dutifully for this, but nothing seems to give me answers to these specific questions... much appreciated.

Comment: 3. seems kind of strange to me, there is nothing 'default' or 'priority' about it, the library implementers simply created a class that implements `Document` since that is the 'contract' they want to provide, and then instantiate that class (a la `new DeferredDocumentImpl(...)`) to return as the result of `parse`.

Comment: Thx for the response. So the spirit of the question is this: what happens if more than one class (say, class B in addition to class A) in the library implements the Document interface, and I execute that same parse(); when I call doc.getClass(), I assume I'll only return either A or B (since an object can only be of one class type). Which one will it be? How and where is it set, if I only fire parse() which returns a Document reference, that it will be an object of type A or B? Is one the default?, the priority? That's what I meant by that. Any insight appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

> am I indeed executing the implemented methods of that DeferredDocumentImpl class?

yes

> An interface can be implemented by any number of classes, and assuming that org.w3c.dom.Document is indeed implemented by multiple classes, why did the Document type returned by parse() get cast as the DeferredDocumentImpl class, and not one of the other classes that implements Document?

You would need to read the code to determine why that library returned that implementation. I wouldn't be surprised if its the only implementation that library has.

Note: org.w3c.dom.Document is an API standard interface, a library which implements this API need only provide one implementation.  A library doesn't have to create an implementation from another library.

> Assuming that 2. above is some kind of 'default' or 'priority' type-assignment, where do I verify - and possibly change - that assignment?

Yes, change the object the library creates by modifying the source of the library.

> How would I override the type-assignment I describe in 3. above at the level of the code itself?

Checkout a copy of the source, change it and built it.

Comment: Peter, can you elaborate on
Note: org.w3c.dom.Document is an API standard interface, a library which implements this API need only provide one implementation. A library doesn't have to create an implementation from another library.

I'm using J2SE-1.5; are you saying that if an interface is supplied in that library, at least one implementation of it MUST also be supplied? And when you refer to 'another library', does that mean the com.sun... library?

Comment: When you implement an API which has an interface you must provide a class which implements it otherwise you are not implementing that API. The interface is provided by a standard body w3 https://www.w3.org/2003/01/dom2-javadoc/org/w3c/dom/Document.html but they don't provide an implementation. The JDK has an implementation for that interface. BTW it's time to upgrade as Java 5 is more than ten years old. I don't know of another library which supports that interface, so there might actually only be one implementation. for a version of Java.

Comment: Indeed! It's an old project from about six years ago; I'm just revisiting it in another context

Thanks so much for the responses, very helpful.